# Adding disk space to a running MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I'm running a MySQL (5.7) on a Centos7 server which also has a replica (slave) on another machine. The problem is that the `master` instance is running out of space and I need to extend its disk space to prevent any failures.

I was wondering that is it possible to add a new physical disk device and extend the current volume with `lvm` **with OR without downtime**? If so, should I be concerned about anything after doing that?

And if it isn't a good practice and shouldn't be done on the production, what are the options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the device is connected to your host, you can add it as a physical volume, then use `vgextend` and `lvextend`, and then finally increase the filesystem to use the volume.

Detailed instructions here: https://www.2indya.com/how-to-extend-your-disk-by-adding-another-without-downtime-using-lvm/

I would always recommend to try out new procedures like this in a test environment first, so you get comfortable with the steps before trying it in production.

Comment: Is MySQL compatible with this VG extension operation? Does it affect MySQL performance?

Comment: I recall doing this once before on a running MySQL system, but it was years ago. As I said, you should test it yourself to be sure. Do not make such changes to production as your first time doing it.

Comment: There is no doubt, however, that adding a new physical drive to your server will require downtime.

Comment: I will test it on another server but I can not test the performance since it's not the production environment and load/connections will be a lot lower than what it would be on the production. Any suggestion about how to test/benchmark the performance?

Comment: https://github.com/akopytov/sysbench is the best benchmark tool for MySQL. You can run a benchmark as a baseline, then run a benchmark while you extend the volume group and filesystem.